# Approaching Input/Output Error when trying to crop data image file

Tags: python, pandas, image

Currently learning reading image by csv and crop it with the data in the csv and i got I/O Error at my data image

the csv has data like below

```
filename    width   height  class   xmin    ymin    xmax    ymax
Data16_173_55.jpg   600 338 Membuka Smartphone  476.25  100.14815   518.125 148.03148
Data16_173_56.jpg   600 338 Membuka Smartphone  474.68753   95.14074    517.1875    153.0389
Data16_173_57.jpg   600 338 Membuka Smartphone  468.125 93.26296    518.125 149.5963
Data16_173_58.jpg   600 338 Membuka Smartphone  470.3125    101.08704   519.0625    148.34444
```

and i am currently trying to crop it and replace the image using looping code by reading the filename, here's the **code**

```
import shutil
import os
from PIL import Image
import cv2
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('labels.csv')
for index, row in data.iterrows():
  input_name  = os.path.join("imagesXRP", row["filename"])
  xmin  = row["xmin"]
  ymin = row['ymin']
  xmax  = row["xmax"]
  ymax = row['ymax']
  im = Image.open(input_name)
  im1 = im.crop((xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax))
  im1.save(input_name)
```

any answer would be help

thank you so much !

`OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error: 'imagesXRP/Data16_173_55.jpg'`

i did try os.path.exist to the file/input image and it works fine without error, the system detect the input

Comment: From which directory your script is executed? Try to display `print(os.getcwd())` at the beginning of your script.

Comment: With your code, I suppose your script and your csv files are in the same directory and in this directory, you have a folder 'imagesXRP' with your images. That's right?

Comment: @Corralien hi sorry for the late reply, yes thats right

Comment: What is the output of `print(os.getcwd())`

Comment: the output is the drive place, /content/drive/MyDrive/Kuliah/Tugas_Akhir

Comment: @Corralien in this Tugas_Akhir folder theres imagesXRP folder